# PHP attribute construct call

Tags: php, attributes, php-8

I want to execute code everytime a apecific attribute is assiggned to a function.

For example:

```
<?php
#[Attribute]
class exampleAttribute
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "exampleAttribute called";
    }
}

#[exampleAttribute()]
function exampleFunction()
{
    //...
}
```

But in this example the echo statement is never called. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are not instantiated automatically, because there is no particular time when they "become attached" - they are just part of the definition of that function, like the types and argument names.

Instead, you have to access them via reflection, as [discussed in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.reflection.php). Specifically, you would use a `ReflectionFunction` object to *read* the attribute, and then the `newInstance` method to *instantiate it*. Only when you do that will your `echo` line run.

Comment: So, is there a way to get all funtions with a specific attribute?

Comment: @AaronJunker Not that I know of. I think the common approach is to have a script loop over everything, and generate a cache of sorts based on the results.